# Directional derivative and unit vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Given this function:

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{x^3 + 2y^3}{x^2 + y^2} &  (x,y) \neq 0 \\ 
0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

- Find the directional derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n} (0,0)$ for each unit vector $n$.
- In which direction the directional derivative is the biggest?

---

I know that $f_{\vec{n}}(0,0) = \nabla f(0,0) \cdot \frac{\vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||} $

And because $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector: $||\vec{n}|| = 1$  and thus we have that the directional derivative is: $f_{\vec{n}}(0,0) = \nabla f \cdot \vec{n}$

But I don't know how to continue from here... how does the vector $\vec{n}$ comes into play in this question?  If the function takes $0$ at the point $(0,0)$ ... I would appreciate your kind help, thanks!

Comment: Write $\vec n=(x_0,y_0)$ and define $h(t)=f(tx_0,ty_0)$. Compute $h'(0)$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Why are we multiplying $\vec{n}$ by t ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a unit vector, then $n=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, for some $\theta\in\Bbb R$. And the directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction given by $n$ is\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(hn+(0,0))-f(0,0)}h&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^3\cos^3\theta+2h^3\sin^3\theta}{h^3}\\&=\cos^3\theta+2\sin^3\theta.\end{align}It is not hard to prove that the maximum value of this expression is $2$, attained when $\theta=\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your awesome answer! - I have a question - is $cos^3 {\theta} + 2 sin^3 {\theta}$ as a final answer fine? or we need to compute it back to algebraic form (not polar) Thanks!

Comment: All I can say is that I would accept that as an answer, if it is stated along with it that the unit vector is $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks you sir, one last question, I can take the derivative to get the critical points of the trigonometric function $cos^3 ( \theta ) + 2 sin^3( \theta) $ - and get it is indeed at 90 deg. (= $\frac{ \pi}{2}$ rads) - but what stops me from taking $ 2 \pi + \frac{ \pi}{2}$ for example? which is still the critical point. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but it's the same direction! After all$$\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right),\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right)=\left(\cos\left(2\pi+\frac\pi2\right),\sin\left(2\pi+\frac\pi2\right)\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Hey sir, sorry for asking again, so does that mean the direction in which the directional derivative is maximal is $(\cos (0.5 \pi), \sin( 0.5 \pi) ) = (0,1)$ - but what other's did is said that the maximal directional derivative is the same as the gradient, and the gradient is $(1,2)$ because: $ \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ f( \Delta x, 0) - f(0,0) }{\Delta x} = \frac{ \Delta x}{\Delta x} = 1$ and so on for $f_y (0,0) = 2$ and so they got $(1,2)$ and we got $(0,1)$ So which way is correct? thank you!

Comment: That way of computing the direction in which the directional derivative is maximal (I mean, using the gradient) works for differentiable functions, but your function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you sir, so they are wrong in that sense, and the answer is really $(0,1)$ Thanks again!